# Manipulate request in REST API (Spring )

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

From the front end if i am getting a request to the backend, is it possible to manipulate the request or dataa before reaching the backend call . And do we have any spring validator to check if the incoming request is correct or not

Comment: yes we can do,you are looking for what type validation..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this using interceptors: Interceptors are used for

1. To intercept a call before receiving to backend controller or
2. Intercept return from controller to client

Use the following link for a comprehensive guide on spring interceptors

Resource: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_boot/spring_boot_interceptor.htm

You should be using `@PostHandle` method in interceptors for your use case.

Answer (score -1):

Create the entities you are expecting as part of the request with propers validations(NotNull, etc).

```
@Entity
public class Entity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

@NotBlank(message = "Name is mandatory")
private String name;

// standard constructors / setters / getters / toString
}
```

At the time defining request mapping add @Valid annotation as below:

```
 @PostMapping("/test")
ResponseEntity<Object> addUser(@Valid @RequestBody Entity entity) {
    // persisting the user
    return ResponseEntity.ok("User is valid");
}
```

Comment: Request validation does not protect against json manipulation.